# The IT department bottlenecks progress. How should I handle this?

Tags: etiquette, colleagues

I'm currently working as a PhD student.

I am not working on a tech-oriented PhD. However, my project requires **a lot** of programming. This involves both working on a computation cluster, servers, and working with a variety of software. These are provided and maintained by our faculty IT support.

Now on the reason why I post: the first problems started when working on our server, maintained by our IT staff. I required some software essential to do my work, but because I have no administrator rights, I cannot install what I need. I asked IT *very* politely (I'm the new one after all), and they let me know that they would handle it as soon as possible.

**Two weeks later**, I still did not have access to the software I desperately needed to do my work. I had to ask my promotor (luckily a huge help in this matter) to ask IT, and finally the software was installed.

The following cycle continued until now:

1. I notice that software is missing / outdated / not working properly
2. I ask IT to fix the issue, because no other options are available
3. IT ignores my requests, leading to me having difficulties to meet deadlines
4. Someone with better credentials has to pressure IT into fixing the issue

Like I mentioned earlier, I absolutely love programming and computers in general, so I can fix almost all issues myself. However, my hands are tied because I have no administrator rights, and IT goes to great lengths to avoid that a non-IT person does something / installs something on one of the computers...

Does some here have similar experiences, and do you know how to smoothen this out? I obviously don't want to cause a ruckus in our department, but I also believe it to be unfair that we are blocked from doing our job. I'm not the only employee who was bottlenecked by IT, so I guess all suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Is there any chance of you installing your required software in your home directory rather than as root?

Comment: Having been on the IT department side of this, and in case you're curious, the most likely reason for their behavior is that they have a lot of more urgent work that they are catching up on, and only once someone higher up the ladder *makes* your request urgent does it get ahead of all the other things. To the detriment of the work on other things. So for what it's worth, they are probably not ignoring you for any personal reason, they are just scrambling to keep the servers running.

Comment: In the meantime, you could try to have things working in your computer, with a smaller dataset. This way, you know exactly what you need to make your thing work and you can go to your professor to ask them to ask IT to install all you need at once, instead of doing the cycle you describe.

Comment: This situation is very common. Have you talked to other PhD students and other staff? How do they handle it? If no procedure is in place I suggest you get familiar with installing software manually (either from source or from binary packages) in your home directory. I’ve ended up doing this at all institutes I worked at. Depending on your cluster, you might also have permissions to spin up Docker instances.

Comment: @user4052054 Yes I do that most of the time, or I try to find ways to work with what is already available (even though that might not be the most straightforward solution sometimes).

Comment: @ToddWilcox I understand that, everyone tries to do what they have to do. It's just that the contact between the researchers and the IT department is not always as effective as we want it to be. This leads to miscommunication, or in the worst case: frustration. That was the aim of this question: to find a way out that allows for everyone to do their work as effective as possible, without causing a ruckus / disturbing other people's work

Comment: @KonradRudolph Most researchers I heard talking mention that they have to mail / pass by several times before action is taken. Supervisors help out more than once (by being in cc, or actually meeting with IT) to arrange help. The home folder and virtual environments have helped me out so far indeed. It's just that I would like to handle this situation without risking difficult social situations

Comment: A lot of IT departments are like that. It is likely that over time you'll make some connections with people there and they will become more helpful. At the same time, plan to do as much as possible without admin rights; for example, if we're talking about a single Linux machine, a lot of software you can compile and install manually, without using the package repositories.

Comment: Does anybody *not* have this experience? This is what IT departments ***do.*** It's the easiest way to meet their objective of "reducing expenditure."

Comment: If you do manage to find a solution to this, let me know. It plagues Academia, Industry, Government, and basically every institution with an IT department.

Comment: Sometimes you can request to become a administrator of your machine. Atleast its possible in most of the universities i have visited. Thing  is though, you need to know to ask for this. They dont usually go around telling  about  this option. However, thay do require you to be remotely competent at what  you do and it may have some consequences on the legal side. This is what  i have done, though i would prefer not to. Anyway once you can show you can handle yourself, thay can then expand you to a network admin on a subset.

Comment: The only thing you can do is to try to prepare a complete list and have it installed by escalating your request. Building personal contacts also helps in these matters. And of course trying to avoid the need for root. It’s also a good idea to remind IT that you are waiting.

Comment: Almost every IT department is under-staffed, because management treads it like facility management: you have to have it, but it has no business value. They do not notice the problems, because their requests are always fulfilled immediately.

Comment: to go along with the generally correct but unfortunate stereotypes being lobbed at IT depts, they also have their own policies and procedures to follow, especially regarding federal security and compliance statutes, and industry level compliances that must be maintained that require extensive documentation and understanding before they can just be installed as though it were your home computer. Also remember it's probably a team of less than 20 people serving your *entire* university. Maybe cut them a little slack or ask for a dedicated environment that is hosted off the primary network....

Comment: To follow up on NKCampbell's comment, IT and the end users have different requirements placed on them. I have been pure research (Ph.D. in a physical science), mixed environment (embedded IT support in a research environment), and now a pure IT position (IT in a government national laboratory). I have governance policies that I have to enforce even if they impede the science. I would like to give you whatever you ask for but I can't. I also have to consider the 500+ other users on the systems so when your request will break other applications you put me in a bind for the greater good.

Comment: I once asked my IT administrator for permission to use an extension cord, so I could plug my laptop, because all the existing sockets were used due to all of us there using dual monitors (we were doing medical imagine research and need to visualise complex datasets effectively). The reply was 'perhaps we should reconsider our dual-monitor policy'. I never asked IT for anything ever again.

Comment: The big issue of IT departments is that they **think** they are in charge and forget that they are a **service** to the other departments...

Comment: @Chris you have to brave out slow responses due to IT understaffing OR you can actually opt out, and be your own IT - you get more flexibility this way but the tradeoff is you get even less support. See my answers below for details on ways to install software yourself.

Comment: @SolarMike The big issue with certain users is that they forget IT is a service to all the other departments and not just to them or their group.

Comment: [Related](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/35893).

Answer (score 50):

This is a partial solution I've used myself, and it assumes a few things:

- You access your clusters remotely through a connection (like other answers pointed, cloud servers or remote), so where you work isn't exactly the bottleneck.
- The software you use isn't OS dependent or has any special licenses
- You do not have a ton of things hooked up from serial ports to measuring equipment and whatnot.

---

One thing I've done in this situation is, when you finally grab a ticket from IT, ask them to **install a virtual machine like VirtualBox and have them enable virtualization in the BIOS**. Most processors allow this nowadays. Make sure they install it properly or they will ghost again.

This basically allows you to install **any Linux distribution** you want (you need Licenses for Windows images), so it is an operating system where **you have all admin rights**. This *completely* removes the IT middleman if your case is just coding and clustering the data crunching since you don't need their permission to do things in the VM, and also shouldn't impact performance significantly.

If IT is worth half a dime, they will appreciate the solution, since:

- It takes gargantuan effort to compromise the Host Machine through a VM if you are not malicious
- Resulting lack of tickets from you needing something updated/installed.

Worst case scenario you can still alternate between both Operating Systems, and do small things in the VM with your admin rights.

Comment: Thank you for this information, also a valuable solution indeed! Both the cloud idea and this one might come in very handy!

Comment: I'm not sure about university IT departments, but in other areas, a user that does not have admin rights to a server cannot have a VM on that server with admin rights on the VM either. In other words, I've never worked in an IT department where this request would be granted. Something that *would* work in my experience is getting approval from your department or program for money for a virtual machine on a cloud service like AWS or Azure.

Comment: @Todd: In principle, anything a user in as an admin guest OS can also be done as a user host OS.  Depending on how the IT department models threats, this sort of request might be granted.  Where things get problematic is with VM-based security systems.  E.g., Windows 10 environment has a feature called Device/Credential Guard.  This security feature tends to prevent VM software from functioning.  Even if the IT department is willing to toggle the BIOS virtualization settings, they'll probably be far less willing to disable Device/Credential Guard.

Comment: If the only time you need admin rights is the installation then a singularity container should do the trick. One of these things; https://www.sylabs.io/docs/ afak they are cli only, but otherwise they are basically a virtual box with better pass through. You can set it up as admin on your own machine then move the image to the cluster and run it there as a normal user.

Comment: @Todd Wilcox: As of a couple years ago, you could get a free student account on AWS. Depending on what the OP's computation needs are, that might serve.

Comment: Considering that a great many "servers" these days are virtualized to begin with, it's not that simple to ask for a VM any more. Nested virtualization has a whole lot of challenges. Also I don't understand what tools people are running that require admin permissions. I've worked on tons of clusters where I simply installed all my programs for the my user.

Comment: @Voo The difficult part is usually installing the dependencies needed for compiling the software without using a package manager. It's possible to learn to do it properly without admin rights, but it tends to take longer than finishing a PhD.

Comment: With a hypervisor cluster like oVirt or Proxmox, it's easy to delegate some resources (storage, virtual CPUs, RAM) to unprivileged users and they can then run their VM(s) on the cluster. The cluster itself consists of identical nodes, perhaps hyperconverged virtualization and storage, and nobody manages the association between VMs and hypervisors manually: it's all automated (say by oVirt engine). Any user can be granted some resources, and how they partition those between the VMs under their control is up to them. Admin access on VMs is then irrelevant: they are isolated from everything else.

Answer (score 24):

I think this is a fairly common occurrence in many companies. There is a big disconnect between the researchers trying to do their work and the IT staff who may be under-resourced, under-trained or limited by administrative policy. In my experience there is often lots of worry about researchers installing software without fully understanding the security implications. In short, I would not expect you to be able to change this policy and it may well be in place for sound reasons.

One solution that has been suggested to me is that academics can apply for time using different cloud compute solutions (e.g. Google compute https://cloud.google.com/edu/, Microsoft Azure https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/education/, any many more). If successful you will be given compute time in a virtual machine where you will have appropriate administrative rights to install any software you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand your point, a lot of people just install random software without thinking through what it does to their computer (or the network the computer is connected to). The cloud is indeed a solution I did not immediately think of (I thought it was always a paying service, but I see that they also award grants for using the cloud in academic settings). I will definitely look into it!

Comment: This might come in very handy but be aware that there might be data security implications. Uploading research data to anywhere outside of my institution's network, especially to US-based servers, could very much be a punishable offense where I work. Of course this might depend on the project, type of data etc and it might well go unnoticed, but it's worth mentioning I think.

Comment: @speedymcs Absolutely. OP needs to get permission from the relevant people, in writing. One web app I maintain at my old university has to be restricted to one university building, and faculty who want to connect outside the building have to use the university's VPN. It's locked down even to me (VPN + 2-factor auth) as the developer. Universities take data exposure very seriously, so make sure you can actually use the data and protect it in the right way!

Answer (score 20):

We had this issue with some Silicon Graphics machines - we removed them from the IT department's control, with the support of the supervisors whose budgets had paid for them, and then controlled **everything** ourselves.

It went much better; we had more uptime and fewer issues than any other group / team on campus.

We learnt **a lot** about compiling & installing etc.

Not sure if you can go that route.

Note, the software we were using was CFD and the IT dept had no experience of what was needed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Well, the problem is indeed that it is not possible for us to separate ourselves from IT using budget. The infrastructure we are working on belongs to the university, and the maintenance is a job for department IT. We indeed try to do as much as possible when it comes to the software we use (and this indeed works quite well), but being completely free from IT is really difficult I think.

Comment: How long ago was this? Today, I'd expect the response to be that the IT support team can't afford for you to be the ones who learn a lot about what happens when you get hacked. Also, nothing in the question suggests that there's money available for duplicating facilities provided by the department. (The asker is using central resources, not resources that belong to the group but which are centrally managed.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby They were on an internal network - no external hacking possible.... Funding was by particular research projects not "central" .... Unless **you** can hack via the power cord...

Comment: @DavidRicherby It's extremely rare in the US to not have group computers self managed, where the only thing IT requires is current antimalware. They're going to have to adapt quick: had several cases recently where instead of using a university HPC cluster, we just went to Amazon AWS or Microsoft Azure since there you install anything you want on your VM, get the right amount of RAM, cores, storage and GPU, and don't have to wait in line.

Comment: @user71659 OK but the computers in the question aren't group computers, and there's no indication whatsoever that the group can afford to buy their own computers to replace the central ones.

Comment: @SolarMike An air-gapped internal network also means no network-based software updates (and burning a CD to run an update is a pain), installing extra software and the prerequisites for the software is difficult, getting to a login prompt is usually hard. Email and network shares are out of the question. Unless you're running FISMA-high data, I would not recommend going in this route.

Comment: @DougO'Neal A cd is **far** better than trying to do a back-up from a tape drive...

Comment: @SolarMike I agree. But when you're under FISMA regulations, a GAO audit, and a government department pushing you out as a guinea pig for the GSS audit, one gets concerned about how often you can update your servers and how hard it is to do so regularly.

Answer (score 13):

At many universities, you can actually go through a (rather secret) bureaucratic process that allows you to install your own software on the university computer, even though this is not the default option.

If this option exists, it will likely include signing forms that may limit (or even eliminate) future IT support for that computer. Basically, you are agreeing to be your own IT in exchange for flexibility. However, if you are constantly downloading software it is often worth it.

The University doesn't want to encourage this option, because it can be a perceived security risk, so you will have to directly ask administrators in your department and IT, if this option is available, as it likely won't be published online anywhere. And you may have to assertively push for it.

This process was available to me at two of the three universities I've been based at over the years (in the USA and Australia). The one that didn't allow it actually theoretically did, but the form also said that you would no longer be able to connect to the Universities wired internet network, which wasn't worth giving up for me. Read the forms very carefully before you go down this route to make sure you are comfortable with the tradeoff you are making.

Comment: Upvoted and agreed. I was at my current academic position for about 10 years before I accidentally discovered (arising from similar complaint to my chair) that we could request having my office computer be "unlocked" so I could install my own software. Meanwhile, my chair was surprised that this hadn't been done for me years earlier (CS department here).

Answer (score 11):

Whilst others have focused on giving you some technical advice on alternatives to using your institution's infrastructure, I want to note that your problems are not uncommon. In my practice I opted to installing the software myself (a lot of software packets I used do not need root privileges for installation, make sure that admin access for yours is really a must) or asked supervisor for help.

If you are on good terms with your supervisor, you can always ask him for help, going from as little as cc-ing him in  software installation emails that you send to your IT department to directly asking him for help when those request emails are ignored. In many organizations it's not easy for junior members to be listened to and that's just something you have to get over with.

Comment: Thank your for answering. Yes, I execute several applications as 'non elevated' user because that will give me what I need in most programs. My supervisor is indeed a big help and, for now, asking the supervisor is the best workaround. Yes, I understand that this is not a rare problem, especially for new employees like myself. However, what annoys me is that the things I ask are really not that difficult. I'm usually merely asking to install a certain software update or library that could come in handy, which is not something that takes weeks to complete.

Comment: Upvoting for the second part here - always CC someone with more leverage whenever you report issues.  Just that frequently moves it up in priority a surprising amount.

Comment: Will chime in that as an admin (non-IT), receiving a cc with the PI is essentially "failing at your job". It is the form of accountability that staff relies on. So as much as we groan when we are at fault, it's absolutely the go-to for reminding other staff that we aren't doing this for our health--other, more important people care about this too. We have a million competing priorities, so unfortunately the squeaky wheel gets the oil... running from emergency to emergency...

Comment: Upvoting for the second part here.  On the one hand, it is **your advisor's** job to make sure you have the IT resources you need.  On the other hand, your advisor has actual leverage with the IT admins; you don't.  Always CC your advisor, and ask your advisor to follow up immediately with "I concur with / approve this request."

Answer (score 7):

Since you're not in a "tech-oriented PhD", I'm guessing the cluster is 10 machines or less? If so, consider setting up your own cluster on any of the big cloud providers. AWS and Azure come to mind, but Google and IBM are still trying to hang on in those markets.

Thoughts on pricing:

- You don't have to have the cluster up all the time, so you don't have to pay for 24hrs/day for a full month. You would have to figure out how to save/load the data and install some programs quickly (docker?), if you opt for shutting down some or all servers.
- If you have fellow students or professors who are in the same boat, consider sharing your cluster and its expenses.
- Depending on your research, you might (eventually) be able to get special pricing from some vendors.
- On AWS, reserved instances are cheaper than spot instances.

Look at how much your time is worth, and how much these delays are impacting your research. If IT delays cost you 1 week of delays every month, then it's probably worth setting up things yourself. (Remember to back things up, and test your backup strategy. Put your code and data in github)

And lastly, are you using their ticketing system for your requests, or just asking them verbally? If there's no ticket, it'll surely be forgotten 5 minutes after you spoke to them.

Comment: This answer _may_ apply, but I don't see where you take the logical step from “not-tech-oriented” to “probably cluster <10 nodes”. In fact, to me, needing a cluster at all while not doing tech actually suggest more likely that _lots_ of nodes are involved. Science or data science applications tend to be really computation intensive. Furthermore, many of these applications are quite latency-critical and only perform properly when run on an actual physical cluster with native MPI support and a suitable file system like Lustre.

Comment: Doesn't AWS EMR allow for there to be clustering on demand in this case?

Answer (score 7):

You should also be managing your requests.

I mean: track when you raised the request, ask for news after a reasonable period of time (two working days), repeat that max three times. In the first follow-up you can make it clear why this is important to you. For IT staff it might sound like 'I want this tool installed', but if you detail the deadline you have and why this ticket is  crucial for your work, they might understand. After the third time, get your supervisor involved. Ask him/her to escalate the request in a conversation with an IT service manager.

Don't be happy with simply solving the ticket, try to see if IT can communicate what time of service level agreement they aim to respect. Maybe installing something requires internal permissions (release management) which, for instance, makes it impossible to install stuff on a Friday, or an afternoon, or if you don't have a rollback (meaning you have to backup the entire server setup before touching anything), etc.

Managing the request also means making sure your requirements are *super*clear. If you think you might need a package ask them to install it. Run these installations yourself in a VM that is identical to the production setup and provide them with the commands to actually install the tools. All these things you can manage.

At all times, and I must stress that, be nice. Just be nice. Unless you have reasons to suspect someone is trolling you, you have to give them the full credit for having to tackle many such requests at the same time. Being nice will get you further on the long run. It will also show to your supervisor that you are capable of creatively handling difficult situations.

Comment: Tagging onto this answer: When following up, use multiple modes if possible.  For example, start with the ticketing system, but do the first follow up by phone.  Being nice *and* tech-savvy on the phone can work wonders with some IT departments.

Comment: As an experienced computer tech, I'd have to add that the IT dept. might already have an agreed upon Service Level Agreement (SLA) as to how soon tickets need to be addressed. Some can be as long as a week or to. The OP stating they need to get their software in only 2 days may require extra steps, signatures, or could just be flat out denied due to this prior SLA. I'd suggest the OP finds out what the Standard Operating Procedure (SOP) is before stating any time limits. And being nice is always a good way to stay off the bad side of the IT dept., cause that's a bad side to be on.

Comment: And you need to remember that the SLA is based on the worst-case workload that IT can reasonably expect. In my organization, we promise through an SLA that a reasonable VM will be created within two weeks. In practice, the timeframe is generally within two day and that's only because we have to depend on two other outside groups for part of the process.  Also, if installation of your software involves installing multiple cutting-edge packages that affect other users, understand that IT has to support everybody, not just your research needs.

Answer (score 4):

Adding this since nobody's mentioned it yet: You could ask your supervisor about having a meeting between you, your supervisor and someone from IT.  Maybe even invite them to lunch if it's appropriate to your institution and situation.  In case they're overwhelmed by tickets and/or they feel like your tickets come in from a faceless ticket-generator, it could help to meet the real researcher behind them.  And you can meet the real person handling the tickets, and see if there's any way you can make your tickets more straightforward for them.

Answer (score 1):

Talk to your supervisor ("promotor"?) about the issue, and suggest that you should get a server that *you* manage. Depending on circumstances, you can agree on a physical server, an upgrade to you workstation / laptop to make it usable as a server, or even a server instance which is completely external to your institution, like Amazon AWS.

If your supervisor insists that you must use the existing IT infrastructure, send your support requests to them the next day after contacting IT. Don't wait for two weeks. Either helping you with these requests is not much of a burden, or your supervisor will grow tired of this and do something about it.

Answer (score 1):

Was this a phone call or an email?  I find things usually get done faster if you call rather than email.  If the communication is time-sensitive you should especially always call instead of email.  An email can easily be missed or ignored until after the deadline.

When it comes to technology most people expect instant gratification.  Technology is supposed to speed things up and make our lives easier, isn't it?  Perhaps it does for the end-user but from an IT perspective it's a much different story.  Life is much more complicated for the developer or IT professional who has to set it all up and maintain the systems.  It takes time.  Technology is never a 100% perfect solution and there's a lot of complicated and time-consuming stuff going on behind the scenes that most end-users aren't aware of.

Comment: +1 for synchronous communication. Unlike an e-mail, a phone call cannot be ignored until later (possibly forever). Even better, visit the IT team physically (if both you and them don't work remotely).

Answer (score 0):

[my.back had a good answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/126899/17534), and it sounds like this may be the way to go when working through a bureaucracy where some of the solutions which involve some variation of "use your own hardware" just aren't practical. To add to this, I've found the following technique useful when dealing with a department or person who is willing to help, but does things on their own time.

1. CC your supervisor on every request.  This gives your supervisor a chance to give you feedback if you request something that you might not have realized was not necessarily what you need, or should be asking, but also lacking a response from your supervisor, it let's the person doing the thing that needs to be done know that your supervisor is aware of the request. (make sure you follow the advice given by my.back when making this initial request as far as why you need it, and when you need it)
2. When you don't get a response within a reasonable amount of time, send the request again, but make sure you that you put in the request itself "Second Request", making sure to again cc your supervisor on the request.  This lets them know that you still do need this thing to be done, it tends to have an effect of increasing the urgency of the IT professional for your task.  Repeat as necessary, making sure to put your request number in the request each time.

In my experience a second request is generally all that is needed when using this technique unless the department is just completely swamped.  The tricky part is to figure out what time frame is reasonable to complete such a request, and since organizations differ, it's not one that can be answered here.  I would suggest getting to know the folks who are completing your task, so that you can get an idea of what they go through, and so they can see you aren't just asking for ridiculous things and just being demanding all the time, because sometimes it's hard to see the world through other people's eyes without some context.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, just always make the requests through your promotor. Maybe explain to them the pattern you have noticed if they ask why you are going through them consistently.

Alternatively maybe they are doing something different, ask them how they get the IT department to resolve the issues quickly.

Answer (score 0):

As a 2022 answer, I suggest using a controlled environment for your software.
For example, you might be able to lock down all of the programs you need with Conda (which, does not require admin install rights on many machines).
Or, ask IT to install and setup a container program like [Singularity](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.5/user-guide/introduction.html) or [Docker](https://www.docker.com/).

Also, consider looking elsewhere.
You might be able to use [Open Science Grid](https://opensciencegrid.org/) or similar program depending upon your country and university.
Lastly, look for advanced computing centers or similar programs at your university such as Wisconsin's [Center for High Throughput Computing](https://chtc.cs.wisc.edu/) or the [High Performance Computing Center at Texas Tech](https://www.depts.ttu.edu/hpcc/).